# PHP XML Library is not installed Grav Issues Found

Tags: php, grav, scotchbox

I'm just starting to use Grav but I can't proceed as I'm trying to use Grav in my local Scotch Box 3.0. I already have updated PHP using brew on my Mac but It seems like Grav still couldn't find it. Any advice? Thanks

Comment: What's the exact error message or page you see when you try to run it?

Comment: @Jacobm001I'm seeing "PHP XML Library is not installed" with "X" mark on it when I'm opening Grav template's "index.php" and the rest of requirements are checked marked

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're just missing some php packages. Installing them and then restarting your web server should fix the issue.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-dom php7.0-xml
```

Comment: I'm using Mac and when I tried that.. It's not working even if I tried my homebrew... I tried to research this unusual error but it seems like confusing now.